# Determining if a mouse position is near the edges of the browser

Tags: javascript, browser, mouse-position

In a browser, I'm trying to determine if the point representing the mouse position is in what I call an "outer area" . For example, in the image attached, the outer area is the one with a blue background.

[image]

In the code and image W represents the width of the viewport of the browser, while H represents the height, and x,y for mouse position

Right now, I'm using this piece of code to do it:

```
if (((x>0 && x<w1) || (x>w2 && x<W))
    ||
    ((x>w1 && x<w2) &&
      ((y>0 && y<h1) || (y>h2 && y<H))
    ))
    console.log("we are in the outer area")
```

While it works as it is, I'm wondering if is there any better way to it?

Comment: Can I ask you what you're going to make? Is it some kind of "scroll on edge" thing like in most RTS games?

Comment: No. The page won't scroll with the mouse. It's more like I want to set up some data when the mouse is in the outer area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to check if it is more than 0 and less than W, since the pointer x position can't be less than 0 or more than W. The same applies to the Y axis. The following should be enough:

```
if((x>w2 || x<w1) || (y>h2 || y<h1)){
  console.log("We are in the outer area");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could wrap your whole page into a DIV (called `outer`) and then connect to the `hover` event.